# Does a player's high level help attract evolved Pokémon when placing Lure Module?

Tags: pokemon-go

Anecdotally, it seems that when a low-level player places a Lure Module, it attracts first-stage Pokémon, but some times, we get Lure Modules that attract second-stage Pokémon.

**Question**

Does a player's level dictate the evolutionary stage of Pokémon attracted by Lure Modules?

Comment: That's a good question. I'd guess it's still the people's presence that determines the quality and CP, but I'd like to know that, too.

Comment: I have no proof, but I also have seen the behavior you describe. When a lower level player places a lure module, it seems to attract only low level pokemon. When I place one (lvl 18 atm), we get a lot more tier2/3 evolution pokemon.

The CPs obviously vary, but the instances of pokemon seem to be "rarer" pokemon (meaning more variety and more already evolved pokemon).

However, this is purely by observation. It could be coincidence/placebo. Idk. But I have a strong inkling that this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

There is no evidence of trainer level affecting what gets spawned when a lure module is active. It looks like what gets spawned is pretty much just random and independent of the trainer that placed the module.

An interesting [thing](https://m.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4vkcs7/theory_on_getting_better_pokemon_variety/) that I found, however, suggests that placing modules and using incense in relatively unpopulated areas can potentially result in rarer Pokemon spawns.